# Renaming file in a sharepoint Library

Tags: workflow

we have users with contribute with no delete permission who wants to rename files after uploaded. would appreciate any suggestion to achieve that. upgrading their permission is not an option. custom action/workflow  was suggested.
please advice!

Comment: What are the details of the permission level they are using? Is it more of an "add no delete" or can they "add and edit with no delete" for the content. If so they should be able to edit the document properties as expected.

Comment: thank you for the response, they can add, but no edit and delete

Answer (score 2):

I would advise to create a custom permission level. You can create a new, custom permission level, copy the rights from the existing Contribute level, and simply remove delete rights. See this tutorial for instructions on how to create a custom permission level: [enter link description here](https://billing.plexhosted.com/knowledgebase/278/How-to-create-a-new-SharePoint-2013-permissions-level-.html). Then you can assign users or groups to the custom level.

Comment: Kevin, Thank You ! I will give that a try, though I doubt they will allow me to change permission. (we are funny with permission here)

Comment: I agree you can create a permission level to add/edit but no delete. It is pointless to create a workflow to do what a different permission level can enable users to do.